# Optional chaining arrays in Ionic Framework (typescript) throws error

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, optional-chaining

I want to use optional chaining in my Ionic project but I receive errors even though I use the correct notation.

My code

```js
// Get Array (might be empty)
const array = await getArray();

return array?.[0];
```

My compiler throws 3 errors:

```
ERROR in path/to/file.ts:12:34 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
[ng] 12         return array?.[0];
[ng]                         ~
[ng] path/to/file.ts:12:34 - error TS1003: Identifier expected.
[ng] 12         return array?.[0];
[ng]                          ~
[ng] path/to/file.ts:12:34 - error TS1005: ':' expected.
[ng] 12         return array?.[0];
[ng]                            ~
```

I don't understand why there is an error. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#array_item_access_with_optional_chaining the syntax would be correct. My IDE (vscode) also doesn't throws me an error

> Array item access with optional chaining You can use bracket notation
> for optional chaining on arrays:
>
> const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; let arrayItem = arr?.[42];

Comment: It sounds like whatever is giving you those parsing errors doesn't understand optional chaining (yet). Your edited question shows `return array?.[0];`, which is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

My typescript-version just seemed to be too old (3.4.3). Optional chaining was introduced in 3.7 (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html), so it makes sense that it does not work in my old version.

I just assumed that my project was relatively up to date but turns out it wasn't.